# All children has rendered in collectionview Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, coverflow

hi I am trying to build [Coverflow](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/) in emberjs using Collectionview

I guess i will be needing css calculations after all children has rendered but i am not able to do it as call back is not triggered in my case

entire bin [enter link description here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/letiwuno/1/edit)
my collection view looks like this

```
App.CoverflowView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    items: null,
    itemSize: null,
    props: ['width', 'Width', 'left', 'Left'],
    itemWidth: null,
    itemHeight: null,
    duration: null,
    current: null,
    elementId: 'coverflow',
    createChildView: function (viewClass, attrs) {
        viewClass = App.CoverView;
        return this._super(viewClass, attrs);
    },
    onChildViewsChanged: function (obj, key) {
        console.log('check');
        var length = this.get('childViews.length');
        if (length > 0) {
            Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'childViewsDidRender');
        }
    }.observes('childViews'),
    childViewsDidRender: function () {
        console.log('childViewsDidRender - count of paragraphs: ');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless the needs of coverflow, i'm assuming it is required to fire the function for each view. In this setup the observer will not fire for property `childViews` for each child view and at first glance of the related code i don't see a property that gets set in order to observe it. So i propose a simple solution, to call the function from `createChildView` since this has been overriden and also keep observing the `childViews` property if the content changes dynamically at some point.

Example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/weleqabu/1  *(look at the console)*

```
createChildView: function(viewClass, attrs){
    viewClass = App.CoverView;
    this.onChildViewsChanged();
    return this._super(viewClass,attrs);
  }
```